# Weird filename when downloading file from Internet Explorer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a webapplication that is set up with a link, and when this link is pressed  then a file is downloaded. The file location right now i is on my own HDD. It works when I download the file from Google Chrome, but when i use IE i get a weird scrambled filename. This is my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage GetFile(string filename, string environment)
{
    _requestLogger.LogRequest(Request);

    var validateResult = new InputValidator().ValidateInput(filename);
    if (!validateResult.IsValid)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ReasonPhrase = validateResult.ErrorMessage };
    }

    filename = SanitizeFileName(filename);

    var filePath = _settings.ResolveFilePath(environment, filename);

    if (!File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
    }

    //Get file
    var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

    //Create result
    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    //Add content to result
    result.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    return result;
}
```

Here is a link to an image of the weird [filename](http://prnt.sc/agpzmq)

I cant seem to figure out why this is happening. Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what i had to do. I created this method and it solved my problem.

```
public static void AddProperFileNameHeadersIfIE(HttpContextBase httpContext, string fileName)
{
    var browser = httpContext.Request.Browser;

    if (browser != null && browser.Browser.Equals("ie", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename*=UTF-8''" + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fileName) + "\"");
    }
    else
    {
        httpContext.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode(fileName) + "\"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the `filename` and `content-length` headers, something like this:

```
result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") {
        FileName = fileName.ToString()
};
response.Content.Headers.ContentLength=stream.Length.ToString();
```